# Publish snapshot artifacts to azure devops artifacts

Tags: maven, gradle, azure-devops

I have a Gradle build set up in Azure DevOps, which compiles the code in an Azure DevOps git repository, then publishes the generated JARs (as Maven artifacts) to Azure Artifacts, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/gradle/publish-package-gradle?view=vsts). Code in other Azure DevOps git repositories can then reference these components as dependencies. This is fine for formal releases of these components (with unique version numbers), but I also need a way to get this working for in-progress snapshot releases. The problem is that I cannot publish an artifact with the same version number (e.g. 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT) more than once. This seems to be because [packages in Azure are immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/immutability?view=vsts).

From my understanding, that would mean that Azure Artifacts cannot be used to store in-progress snapshot artifacts. Is that correct?

If it is, is there any alternative that still uses Azure DevOps? I can see that I can [publish artifacts to Azure Blob Storage](https://dzone.com/articles/host-your-maven-artifacts-using-azure-blob-storage), but presumably this is something you have to pay for on top of existing use of Azure Artifacts. I can also see that there's a number of [GitHub Maven plugins](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins) for treating a GitHub repo as a Maven repo, but I can't find anything similar for using an Azure DevOps repo as a place to publish Maven artifacts.

In case it makes a difference, I'm talking about the cloud-based Azure stuff, nothing on-premise.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm facing a problem where I need to migrate a maven snapshots repo to Azure Artifacts and I'm not sure it can be supported.

Comment: I'm afraid not @TomislavMarkovski. I also suspect it isn't supported. We ended up giving up on using Azure, partially for this reason, and partially because of costs.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for maven, there's a difference in how a jar is packaged in a SNAPSHOT as compared to other versions.

Eg. let's say I version my jar as 1.0.0-PRERELEASE, now this version is immutable. Once I publish this to any artifact repository it cannot be overridden. Usually package management systems store the artifact in this kind of logical path - `<group_id>/<artifact_id>/<version>/<artifact_id>_<version>.jar`.

But for SNAPSHOTs this is slightly different. In maven, SNAPSHOTs are mutable. This means you can override a SNAPSHOT. And this makes sense as by definition SNAPSHOTs are like an image of your code in active development. How SNAPSHOTs are stored in a package management feed is something like `<group_id>/<artifact_id>/<version(SNAPSHOT)>/<artifact_id>_<version>_<jar_timestamp>.jar`.

This naming convention of the jar in this case makes it mutable. In a single SNAPSHOT version, there can be multiple jars present with different timestamps. And when maven looks for a SNAPSHOT dependency to download, it always picks the most recent one (again logical as that's the most recent snapshot).

At present azure artifacts implements these concepts exactly how they are supposed to. Perhaps this wasn't there before and has been pushed in an update.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version
https://xebia.com/blog/continuous-releasing-of-maven-artifacts/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is mostly a feature and not a bug as to preserve the immutability of the build results - meaning, that no matter when that build is ran, it will always return the same result. See: [How to update a maven dependency with a same version number in Azure Artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937667/how-to-update-a-maven-dependency-with-a-same-version-number-in-azure-artifacts) & [Azure Artifact Publishing Fails for Artifact Version Containing '+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210924/azure-artifact-publishing-fails-for-artifact-version-containing)

Answer (score -1):

The premise of Package Management is that a package is immutable. This enables a whole bunch of caching options that would otherwise not exist. Packages are stored in your local package cache, possibly on a proxy feed package cache and all of these elements assume that packages with the same name+version are unchanged and will serve the cached version instead of the latest version you've pushed. Most package systems are built on this premise, including Nuget and NPM.

The trick to creating development snapshots is to use semantic versioning and adding a unique suffix to your version. For example `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.1` followed by `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.2`, there are tools available for Azure Pipelines, like [GitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion) that can automatically generate a unique version + suffix that you can pass into the version for your artifact.

If you don't want to "mess up" your main package feed, you can setup a second feed for development purposes which holds all your intermediate packages, you can then either promote one of these packages to your main feed or you can run a specific pipeline (configuration) to push the final package to the feed used for your stable packages.

Comment: Thats not how maven snapshots work. https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/09/how-does-a-maven-repository-work/#snapshot-repositories

Comment: I get maven works differently. But this is what comes close. You can add views of feeds if you want to. *This* is how package management works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Honestly, for me Azure Artifacts is then not at all a replacement for e.g. a Nexus instance. The sole reason for snapshots is to have defined a `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT` version in your dev branch which will automatically pull the latest dev version (NOT release). If this version needs to be constantly updated, the Azure concept is not suitable here.

Comment: I get a square pegg round hole feeling with Azure devops and non-Microsoft things.