# Azure Artifact Publishing Fails for Artifact Version Containing '+'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have been trying to publish an artifact of a java module (jar) to Azure Artifact and was getting an error 404. 
After debugging for a while i have realised my [semantic version](https://semver.org/#spec-item-10) was breaking the URL.

**1.0.2-beta1+20191202**

The + indicates meta data as part of the semantic version syntax. At the same time he + breaks the URL that Azure creates to upload the artifact.

Here is a sample of the URL that Azure creates:

https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/test/maven/v1/com/MYCOMPANY/test/1.0.22+0110-SNAPSHOT/test-1.0.22+0110000-20102.29-1.jar'

The pluses in the version are causing a 404 error to happen.

Seems like a missing feature but would appreciate if there is a workaround meanwhile this is actually addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Artifact Publishing Fails for Artifact Version Containing '+'

I am afraid there is no such solution/workaround to resolve this issue at this moment.

I got the same 404 error if I Publish Artifact with `+` in the URL. Take long time but did not find any solution/workaround for this issue until I found [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/581881/artifact-publishing-fails-when-artifact-name-conta.html):

The Azure Artifacts Engineering replied:

> Due to **technical limitations in our service's web stack**, we cannot
>   currently support + signs in URL paths. As such, we do not currently
>   support SemVer build metadata (+ suffix) in some package types such as
>   Maven.

I have to accept this technical limitation if I want to continue using Azure Artifacts.

Hope this help you.